# why does keccak256 in assembly require 2 arguments?

Tags: assembly

Why does keccak256() in assembly require 2 arguments? What is the second argument?

```
assembly {
let foo := keccak256(4)
}
```

returns error

```
Function expects 2 arguments but got 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, that is a pointer (start) and a length. The syntax differs from Solidity because the latter gets the location as well as the length from the bytes argument.

Hope it helps.

Comment: etherevm.io is useful for verifying this - https://www.ethervm.io/#20