# How to make inline assembly keccak256 work like Solidity keccak256

Tags: solidity, assembly

Is there a way to use inline assembly `keccak256(p, n)` work like the Solidity `keccak256(p)`? I imagine there would be a neutral input I could give for either `p` or `n` to make that happen?

Comment: What do you mean with "neutral input"? Any input (uint, string, bytes...)?

Comment: @alberto meaning an input to the line assembly keccack256 that along with the intended input would give the same result as calling the Solidity keccack256 with one input.

Comment: Hope I have understood your comment correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79412/why-does-keccak256-in-assembly-require-2-arguments), we know that we need the pointer and the length of the data to use inline assembly `keccak256(p, n)`. Therefore, when using inline assembly `keccak256` you need to indicate the length of the input to use a neutral input.

For this example I will use `bytes` since according to the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) the `keccak256` function receives `bytes`. If you use a different variable type, such as `uint` you need to convert it into `bytes`. So, note that the function should be modified depending on your input.

Hence, one option to make a general function could be the following:

- We need to load the length (first 32 bytes) using `mload(_a)`.
- We need to load the data using `add(_data, 0x20)`. Just to clarify, `0x20` is 32 bytes in `hex`.

Thus, inline assembly `keccak256(p, n)` will have the following parameters:

`keccak256(add(_a, 0x20), mload(_a))`

You can test on Remix the following functions:

```
function solidityKeccak (bytes memory _input) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_input));
}

function assemblyKeccak (bytes memory _input) public pure returns (bytes32 x) {
    assembly {
        x := keccak256(add(_input, 0x20), mload(_input))
    }
}
```

---

Example with a storage reference:

- We need to load the value in storage. Please read the following sections of the docs: [Layout of State Variables in Storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) and [Mappings and Dynamic Arrays](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays).
- Then save the value in memory, preferably in the [free memory pointer](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory) (`0x40`)
- Compute the `keccak256` function by indicating the pointer and the length of the data.

Code to test on Remix:

```
// For dynamic array variables, this slot contains the length.
bytes example = hex"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001234"; // Storage slot #0

function assemblyKeccakStorage () public view returns (bytes32 x) {
    assembly {
        let value := sload(keccak256(example.slot, div(sub(sload(example.slot), 1), 2)))
        let ptr := 0x40 // Free memory pointer
        mstore(ptr, value)
        x := keccak256(ptr, div(sub(sload(example.slot), 1), 2))
    }
}
```

To understand better the code:

- `example.slot` returns `0`.
- `div(sub(sload(example.slot), 1), 2))` is the reverse operation from the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#bytes-and-string):

> For byte arrays that store data which is `32` or more bytes long, the
> main slot `p` stores `length * 2 + 1` and the data is stored as usual
> in `keccak256(p)`.

Comment: Is `add(_data, 0x20)` the storage location for the data?

Comment: @scorpion9979 Is where the data starts, yes. Because the first 32 bytes is for the length, so you need to count after this 32 bytes to get the data.

Comment: Oh, it's the memory location for data because memory layout always has first 32 bytes for length, and then the consequent 32-byte locations for data without any packing (elements padded with zeros).

Comment: Would be great if you could also include an example where the function input is a storage reference.

Comment: @scorpion9979 Done. Just do the same, get the value in storage and then save it in memory. After that, you need to indicate the pointer where the value is stored and the length to compute the ´keccak256` hash.