# Confusion about mload opcode

Tags: evm, yul

This code is used to return keccak256 of function input and taken from [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107348/how-to-make-inline-assembly-keccak256-work-like-solidity-keccak256):

```
function assemblyKeccak (bytes memory _input) public pure returns (bytes32 x) {
    assembly {
        x := keccak256(add(_input, 0x20), mload(_input))
    }
}
```

My question is:

`mload` opcode usually takes memory address and loads what is stored there (such as free memory pointer mload(0x40)). In this case, it takes byte as an input... what is it doing here and what is it loading?

`add` adds two input and returns result. How is it possible to add `_input` with 32?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 points that you should clearly understand in assembly context :

1 . **All variables are value type in assembly**

There is no such thing as a "reference type" in assembly, for instance `_input` in assembly context is the address of the byte array, it's not the byte array itself like in pure solidity. Considering that value as an address (i.e., a pointer) or anything else is just a matter of interpretation, it is by no means enforced by the language.

2 . **Memory arrays have the following layout**

The length of the array is stored at it's address (in that case, the value of `_input` is just the address where you will find the length of the array encoded on 32 bytes), the following memory addresses will contain the data on as much 32 bytes words as necessary.

You can read more about it in [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory).

For a visual explanation, this would be the actual memory layout of the `_input` array if it were composed of 33 bytes each with value `0x01`.

[image]

---

So :

`mload(_input)` loads the 32 byte value contained at the address `_input` (the value of `_input` is an address, the value of `memory[_input]` is the length of the `_input` **solidity array**.)

`add(_input, 0x20)` takes the address `_input` and adds 0x20 (32) to skip the 32 byte length field, the result is the address at which the data is actually starting in memory. Think of it as the address of _input[0] if you want.

`keccak256` ([SHA3](https://www.ethervm.io/#20)) requires both the offset of the data to hash and its length. The offset is just the memory address where the data is starting (`add(_input, 0x20)`) and it's length is `mload(_input)` as we have seen just before.

I hope that answers your question. Don't hesitate to ask for precisions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Wouldn't it is name would be "value type" if _input contains the value itself (the array) rather than the address? I thought since it is address, its reference type not value type

Comment: It's fine to see it like that. My point is that the language doesn't see it that way (it's agnostic to the "type" of the variable, it only sees values, you, as a developer are interpreting their nature). Solidity does enforce types, so adding an array with an integer makes no sense, in assembly, there is no such things as arrays, there are only values that the developer must interpret correctly. Not sure if that makes sense ?

Comment: yes it indeed kinda does. Even if the input was string, it would store the address of the string rather than the value itself right? Do same logic apply there as well since its dynamic value?

Comment: Yes, same goes for memory uint256 array or even memory structs or memory array of structs, it's all the same for assembly anyway, just a bunch of values. That the code (i.e., you) will hopefully interpret and organize correctly.